# How to determine if a integer linear equation with contraints is solvable?

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming, linear-diophantine-equations

I want to write an efficient program to the determine if the following equation is solvable.

The equation and the constraints look like this:
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i=0\quad(\forall i,a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash0,x_i\in\mathbb{Z})\\
&\forall i,|x_i|\le M_i\quad(M_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+)\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|>0
\end{align}$$

After some searching, I found it's somehow related to Integer Linear Programming, which is generally NP-hard. Anyway I hope somebody knows an efficient algorithm for this particular problem and please give me some help.

Thanks

Comment: Are the $a_i$ coefficients fixed?

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, the unknowns are $x_i$s.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic programming approach can work well if the $a_i$ and $M_i$ are not too large.  Let
$T(v,j) = true$ if there is a solution to 
$\sum_{i=1}^j a_i x_i = v$ with $x_1, \ldots, x_j$ integers, not all $0$, with $|x_i| \le M_i$, otherwise $T(v,j) = false$.
Of course it is $false$ if $|v| > \sum_{i=1}^j |a_i| M_i$.  Moreover,
$T(v,j)$ is $true$ iff $v = x a_j$ with $|x| \in \{1,\ldots, M_j\}$ or some $T(v - a_j x, j-1)$ with $|x| \in \{0, \ldots, M_j\}$.  Thus we can compute the $T(v,j)$ recursively in pseudo-polynomial time.  Your problem has a solution iff $T(0, n)$ is $true$; if it is, by tracing backwards through the computed $T(v,j)$ we can construct a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Let $V=\sum{|a_i|M_i}$, so basically I need to evalute $T(v,j)$ for $v \in [-V, V]$ and $j \in [1,n]$, spend $O(M_j)$ time for every $T(v,j)$, totally about $O(nV\sum{M_j})$.

Comment: Actually here $M_i$ represents the length of the i-th dimension of a multi-dimensional array, and $a_i$ represents the stride of that dimension, so may be a little bit too expensive. Anyway, thanks for your nice algorithm!

Comment: Yes, that's a bound.  Except you don't really need to compute all of them, just the ones you need.  In Maple I would define $T$ as a recursive procedure with "option remember", and it'll only compute the terms as needed.